# Adjacent numbers placed in a circle cannot have integer ratios

Tags: number-theory

> Is it possible to place the numbers $1,\ldots, n$ in a circle, such that the ratio between two adjacent integers is it itself an integer?

I think the answer is no for $n\geq 3$, and I would like to prove it without using Bertrand's postulate (because it is to me heavy machinery that I'm not able to prove).

I started out with a simpler exercise where $n$ was odd, and the ratio of adjacent numbers was supposed to be a prime number. This is impossible. Let $a_1r_1=a_2$, $a_2r_2=a_3$, and so on.

[image]

Then $$a_1r_1r_2\cdots r_n=a_1\\\Rightarrow r_1r_2\cdots r_n=1$$ This is impossible as the primes do not come in pairs ($n$ is not even).

I want to generalize to $n\geq 3$ any integer, and also the ratio being any positive integer. It is clear that the case when $n=p$, $p$ a prime, is impossible, as the adjacent integers must then be $1$ and $p$. Also the result would follow if there is a prime $p$ such that $p<n\leq 2p$, which is true by [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Is it possible to prove this result without using Bertrand's postulate?

Comment: Do you allow the ratio between consecutive numbers to be prime *in either direction*, i.e. is $\ldots 6, 12, 4, \ldots$ okay since $\frac{12}{6} = 2$ and $\frac{12}{4} = 3$ are both prime?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes

Comment: The title says cannot have integer ratios but the question demands them.

Comment: Bertrand's postulate is not adapted to this exercice. Select the highest prime number, less than n. This highest prime number whould be between 1 and1 on your circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n=2m$ is even and at least $4$, then any two of the $m$ numbers $m+1,..2m$ cannot be adjacent since the (largest) ratio between them is between $1$ and $2$, hence they must go in $m$ alternate spots, but then $m$ is adjacent to two of them (here we use $m \ge 2$) and the ratio $(m+k)/m, 1 \le k \le m$ is integral only for $k=m$

if $n=2m+1$ then any two of the $m+1$ numbers $m+1,...2m+1$ cannot be adjacent, but that is not possible since there are only $m$ remaining spots and that shows the result in this case

Answer (score 0):

More simple : consider $p$, the highest prime number in range [1,n] and try to build 2 neighbors to $p$.

Comment: I don’t think it is that easy, what if $n=2p+1$? Then we could have $1,p,2p,2$. The existence of largest prime that only appears once from $1$ to $n$ is not that easy to show.